# Layer set visible

Tags: javascript, layers, dynamic

I add this layer like this:

```
var POIData = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://mysite.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/POI_Data/MapServer");
map.addLayer(POIData);
POIData.hide();
```

I want to show it from a button:

This is the button:

```
<div id="POIData" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ToolBarButton" style="float: left;"onClick="showPOI();" >POI</div>
```

And this is the function behind it:

```
function showPOI(){
    POIData.show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any ideas? I just now can't see it, and can't set it to visible.

Comment: Not sure about this..but you can set visible layers.. OR check following example (http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/samples/map_dynamiclayerlist/index.html) (http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/59038-Dynamically-add-layer-to-map-and-populating-sublayers-on-a-list-check-box.)

Comment: Yes i know, but the first example is only for tiled layers

Comment: May be this will be perfect http://efreedom.com/Question/F-2544/Checkboxes-Turn-Layers-Within-Mapservice-Want-Make-Layers-Visible

Comment: So if i set the id to POI... Should i do in the function: POI.show()?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply..yes you can try that